# tried to install spleeter, got miniconda, then anaconda, then python, then it broke and I wanna start over

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, spleeter

Please help I don't know anything about code or anything. I just wanna install spleeter but got and made great progress with the million steps of troubleshooting. Now I wanna delete miniconda, anaconda and python. I went to finder to delete the python folders, then i typed in the code that's supposed to delete miniconda, then anaconda, but it wouldn't stop telling me "ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)" google says that this indicates a python corruption so i told it to downgrade, this didn't work, i tried to put it back, it didn't work
this is so frustrating i just wanna purge it all and try again. It's the only stuff I've ever done with this so if there's like a nuke button, that'd be best

Comment: have you gone through this link https://github.com/deezer/spleeter

Comment: Try uninstalling from system, deleting the files associated manually, and removing any paths that crept into PATH (if windows)?

Comment: @Codeman the thing is, it's all text based. When I search in finder, they don't show up, also nah, it's mac :/ Thanks!

Comment: @niteshrijal no, I downloaded from here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html || Then, I downloaded anaconda proper within it, "conda install anaconda" then told it to install python 3.7, something like "conda install python=3.7

Comment: please go through this link  github.com/deezer/spleeter  and remove completely from your pc and start over